# Why can the variable not be found here?

Tags: javascript

It tells me variable secret can not be found.

```
// Display the prompt dialogue while the value assigned to `secret` is not equal to "sesame"
do {
  let secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
} while ( secret !== "sesame");
// This should run after the loop is done executing
alert("You know the secret password. Welcome!");
```

Comment: `let` has a strict scoping rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: ``do {
       var secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
       } while ( secret !== "sesame");``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 1):

let has block scope. Use `const` or `var`.

```
var secret;  // or const secret;
do {
  secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
} while ( secret !== "sesame");
```

EDIT:
On suggestion of @James

```
let secret;  
do {
  secret = prompt("What is the secret password?");
} while ( secret !== "sesame");
```

will work too since now `let`'s scope is increased by defining it out of `do while` statement's block

Comment: Since you moved the declaration outside the block, you could also use `let` here, but `const` will not work since you are redefining the variable with the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people already commented: `let` has a strict scoping rule.
Use `var` or `const` instead. Or use `let` outside the block, one level higher.

Comment: Do not use const.